# drills for n-gons larger than a square

Tags: geometry

A close approximation to a square hole can be drilled with a drill bit based on the Reuleaux triangle: http://www.etudes.ru/en/etudes/drill/

Are there similar drill bits capable of drilling out close approximations of pentagonal, hexagonal, n-gonal holes?

Is there a way of constructing a bit to drill out any given n-gon, within a reasonable margin of accuracy (rounded corners), if it is possible to add arbitrarily many eccentricities from the central axis?

Comment: The note ["Drilling for Polygons" by Barry Cox and Stan Wagon (PDF)](http://stanwagon.com/public/CoxOddGonDrill.pdf) discusses odd-gonal drills. The references look helpful, too.

Comment: Thanks, Blue. That document looks good. 

Seems the answer to both my questions might be yes.